# Reinstall Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I need to reinstall Xcode. It seems that some of the installation did not work correctly and so I need to completely reinstall it.

Xcode is a pretty hefty piece of kit and so I was wondering how you go about completely uninstalling / reinstalling it?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Apple recommended way to uninstall and install Xcode is in the "Read Me" document that accompanies each release, which basically says launch the Terminal.app then (if you  originally installed Xcode in the standard location) type

sudo /Library/uninstall-devtools --mode=all

You'll be prompted for the superuser id which is generally the same password as the first (non-restricted) user registered on the Mac.

I would recommend you restart your Mac before installing (newer and older) Xcode again.

Comment: @nomad - I have performed the above, and it looks like it woked... however, I still have a /Developer folder which contains several subfolders and files, totalling around 65MB.  Can I get rid of these files?

Comment: @mrwooster: Do not get rid of anything in the Developer folder. That contains links to headers, frameworks, and system resources. The Developer folder is an all or nothing deal.

Comment: But the /Developer folder is not present on a fresh OSX install?  Or is it the remains of the tools that are still required by programs that I have installed since installing xcode?

Comment: If you still see a Developer folder, then I would argue against your use of the term "fresh install". The Developer folder has never been part of a Mac OS X install; Xcode has always been separate and therefore deliberate since most users do not need it. Downloading and installing the latest version of the Developer tools will bring the whole toolkit up-to-date. But, you should just be able to trash the Developer folder in of itself and reinstall without any problems. Just don't delete any individual bits inside to be on the safe side.

Comment: @mrwooster the remnants files in your /Developer is most likely because of the documentation downloaded when your Xcode periodically checks for update. So long as you didn't see any error messages performing the "sudo ..." (for e.g. error messages that suggested some links/files are missing), it's OK to Trash them (after you restart so that these libraries and frameworks are no longer in memory, else you can't empty trash).

Comment: @mrwooster One important note to remember, please use the uninstall script that came TOGETHER with the Xcode version you installed as different Xcode versions may have slightly different scripts. Lastly, don't install different version of Xcode stacked one on top of another -- that's a quick way to potentially have corrupted links that's a pain (doable, but still a pain) to remove.  Please mark your question as answered if this solves the problem you're facing, thanks.

Comment: Dont worry, I wont forget to mark as answered ;)... I used the script that came with that XCode install, and have not installed any other versions.... there are still some files that are not documentation, but I would like to remove them, so going to do a time machine backup and then try deleting.... not ideal, but at least I can restore if it all goes tits up.

Comment: @mrwooster. Sounds like you have successfully removed a clean Xcode install, so doubtful you'll need to restore from a Time Machine. One last tip, maybe helpful to do a Time Machine backup after you've successfully installed Xcode AND downloaded the documentation. Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: Not sure why the difference, but for my Xcode 4 install, the actual command is: sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools -mode=all